# estimate normal distribution parameters by $n$ largest samples

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation

If I have the $n$ largest out of $m$ values of a sample from independent normal distributed random variables $\mathbb{X}_1,\dots,\mathbb{X}_m\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ with unknown parameters $\sigma$ and $\mu$, is there an simple maximum likelihood estimation formula for these?

What for an exponential distribution?

Comment: If you mean $X_1,\ldots,X_m\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.}\  N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and your looking for the $n$ largest among $X_1,\ldots,X_m$, then you're using terminology incorrectly.  Those are the $n$ largest observations in a sample, not the $n$ largest samples.

Comment: If I do my sampling repeatedly, I actually get several independent distributed $X_i$s, if you like to name it so.. 'sampling repeatedly' is not very precise, but I guess as there are no other dependencies on the several samples in the text, it should become clear that the samples are independent realisations of $X$.

Comment: But the standard terminology used by statisticians is that those are observations in a sample.  The "sample" contains all $m$ of them.

Comment: Ok, refined it a little.